# Using Google's T5 for translation from German to English

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, language-translation

I am trying to use Google's T5 for language translation. However, it is not working for German to English.

English to German works fine:

```
self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
self.model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("t5-small")
inputs = self.tokenizer.encode("translate English to German: " + text, return_tensors="pt", max_length=512, truncation=True)
summary_ids = self.model.generate(inputs, max_length=512, min_length=5, length_penalty=5., num_beams=2)
summary = self.tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0])
```

However, changing encoding to "German to English" is not working.

Is this model not intended to be able to translate German to English, or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably very late to the party, but I just printed out model.config as @acivic2nv suggested. It seems like the Google T5 model only supports translations from English to other languages, specifically: French, German, and Romanian.

In case you are still looking for a model that is able to translate from German to English, try using the Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-en! I have had some encouraging results with it.

Here is a quick working example in case it helps:

```
from transformers import pipeline

translator = pipeline("translation", model="Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-en")

text1 = "Dies ist ein Beispieltext."
text2 = "Das ist ein weiterer Beispieltext."

text = [text1, text2]
translated = translator(text)

print(translated)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run print(self.model.config) it will print out what tasks are supported. This will ensure it supports that translation.

You can see this as an example.

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Transformers-for-Natural-Language-Processing/blob/main/Chapter07/Summarizing_Text_with_T5.ipynb